# Make the first child route as the active class whenever the sub-route path is an empty path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a Main Navigation nav bar with some links. In the home page, i.e., in the root path ('/'), I have nested (child) routes.

Route configration:

```
const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: HomeMainContent, children: [
            {path: '', component: MovieList},
            {path: 'in-theaters', component: MovieList},
            {path: 'coming-soon', component: ComingSoonList},
            {path: 'trailers', component: TrailerList},
    ]},
    {path: '/about', component: About},
    {path: '/contact',component: Contact},
];
```

So when the root path `('/')` is active, its child router root path `('')` is activated.

The template of child component router is in this way:

```
<template>
    <div id="homeSubMenuWrapper">
        <ul id="subMenuList">
            <li v-for="menu in menuList">
                <router-link class="menuItem" :to="menu.path">{{menu.name}}</router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                menuList: [
                    {name: 'IN THEATER', path: '/in-theaters'},
                    {name: 'COMING SOON', path: '/coming-soon'},
                    {name: 'TRAILERS', path: '/trailers'},
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Since, both the path `('')` and (`'in-theaters')` have the same component, I would like to make the router-link of path `('in-theaters')` to have the class of `router-link-active` whenever the child path `('')` of its parent path `('/')` is active. How can I do that?

Meaning the first child route `('in-theaters')` should have the active class whenever the sub-route path is an empty path `('')`.

Comment: You can do all sorts of stuff by checking this.$router and this.$route in a computed property.

Comment: @Potray Thanks, I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Potray's advice, I ended up checking the $route.path and the child path inside the template.

```
<template>
    <div id="homeSubMenuWrapper">
        <ul id="subMenuList">
            <li v-for="menu in menuList">
                <router-link  :class="[$route.fullPath ==='/' && menu.path === '/in-theaters' ? 'menuItem router-link-active' : 'menuItem']" :to="menu.path">{{menu.name}}</router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```